# WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file QcFormDean.jsp, but wait its a jsf file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mime-types, web.xml

I just added jstl-1.2.jar, JSF api, and impl jars to my library so that this could work on my jsf xhtml file.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dliStickerValue}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDliSticker" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="perfbyDliSticker">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.performedByRoleID}"
                     rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq  'P'}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Always" />                
        <f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now when i try to access the page on IE i get a *404* missing error and i get the following error on Tomcat and i am not sure what to do at this point the error mentions it as a jsp file and i know i am making this as a jsf file so i am not sure what to do.

> Feb 05, 2014 3:05:50 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
>   WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /preQcFormDean.xhtml.
>
> Feb 05, 2014 3:05:50 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /preQcFormDean.view.xml.
>
> Feb 05, 2014 3:05:50 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
>   WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /preQcFormDean.jsp.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

and this is my web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"                                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                                                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (default). See JSF   Specification section 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>welcome.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and here are the jar files in the lib folder

```
javax.faces.jar 
jsf-api.jar 
jstl-1.2.jar 
jsf-impl.jar
```

Comment: To clarify, what's the file name of your xhtml file and what URL are you trying to access?

Comment: that would be qcFormDean.xhtml xhtml file  and the URL is http://localhost/dli_int_preQc_QC_Forms/preQcFormDean.jsf

Comment: Have you configured the Faces servlet and if yes, can you show the excerpt from your web.xml? Sounds like it isn't picking up your request.

Comment: Your webapp's runtime classpath is a mess. To start nailing it down, please edit your question to include a full list of all JARs in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Added the jars to it, along with the web.xml hope it helps.

Comment: Keep in I have other pages as well and they all show up fine the only issue is this particular page has the panelgroup code and rendered information added on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar`. They are already represented by the single `javax.faces.jar`. Right now you're effectively having **two** different JSF APIs and impls in webapp's runtime classpath which would only lead to class conflicts in all colors.

Big chance that those are actually of legacy JSF 1.x version (you'd first extract the JAR file with a zip tool and then read the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file for the exact version detail) which used the ancient JSP as default view technology which in turn at least explains why all your views were by default interpreted as JSP.

Comment: Tried that and sadly I am still getting these errors

Feb 06, 2014 8:06:00 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /QcFormDean.jsp.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

Comment: should i use a different version of jstl ?

Comment: Then the problem is caused elsewhere not visible in the information provided so far. I suggest to start creating a new JSF project from scratch based on a sane guide/tutorial. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Okay will do would you happen to know of a good tutorial for one in eclipse?

Comment: Thank you I made a new project and while that solved that issue i am now getting a new error saying "<f:ajax> Parent is not composite component or of type ClientBehaviorHolder, type is: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@1d3fdfd" 
So will probably need to make a new question i am guessing but will research what to do.

Comment: Provided that the given code is all you have in a `<h:body>`, then you most likely simply forgot to register the `h:` XML namespace, causing the `<h:selectOneMenu>` to not be interpreted as a real JSF component.

Comment: by that do you mean this? <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >

this was on the xhtml I just didn't add it on the snapshot of the code.

Comment: Here is my new question i posted on this new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606597/fajax-parent-is-not-composite-component-or-of-type-clientbehaviorholder-on-a

Comment: what was your problem, as i am currently getting the same...?

Answer (score 8):

try to add the following lines in the web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: _No mime type could be found for file /preQcFormDean.jsp_ shoud be `<extension>jsp</extension>` to fix.

Comment: <mime-mapping>
    <extension>jsp</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>