# <f:ajax> Parent is not composite component or of type ClientBehaviorHolder on a selection one menu

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to get a second selection method to show up depending on what was selected for the first value. Now i need to do this over 38 times for a form i am making but i want to see if i can get it working for one question first. Here is the code i have so far cut on the jsf page. The values are all the same for the other 38 questions. I just recreated the project and so far the bean is currently empty but i know i should be able to atleast see the form first which is what i am hoping to do for now before i add the values and code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >

    <h:head>
    <title>QC-Form</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <h1 class="title">QC Form</h1>
    <br/> <br/>

      <font face="comic sans MS" size="2" color="#33CCFF">
      <p><b>Enter the information below: </b> </p>
      </font>

    <h:form>

     <font face="comic sans MS" size="2"> 

     <b>Your initials: </b>  
        <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.techNameValue}"/><br/>
    <br/>

     <b>Model #: </b>  
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.modelValue}">
      <f:selectItem itemValue="3600" itemLabel="3600" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="7200" itemLabel="7200" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="8300" itemLabel="8300" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="8400" itemLabel="8400" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="8500p" itemLabel="8500p" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="8800" itemLabel="8800" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="9000" itemLabel="9000" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="9008" itemLabel="9008" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="9200" itemLabel="9200" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="9300" itemLabel="9300" />
    </h:selectOneMenu><br/>
     <br/>

    <b>Date : </b>
     <h:outputText  value="#{currentDate}"/>
    <br/> <br/>


    <b>Serial #: </b>  
        <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.serialValue}"/><br/>
    <br/>

    <b>Customer Name: </b>  
        <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.customerNameValue}"/><br/>
    <br/>

    <b>Special Instructions: </b>  
        <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.specialInstructionsValue}"/><br/>    

    </font>

      <font face="comic sans MS" size="2" color="#33CCFF">
      <p><b>QC Process</b> </p>
      </font>

     <font face="comic sans MS" size="2"> 


     <b>1.Unit Serial number has been applied: </b>
     <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.unitSerialValue}">
      <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not Applicable" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="FAIL-Nonfunctional" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="FAIL-Intermittent" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Incorrect" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="D" itemLabel="FAIL-DLI Standard" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="FAIL-Special Standard" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="G" itemLabel="FAIL-Physical" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <br/>

    <br/>
    <b>2.Screen Protector has been applied: </b>
    <h:panelGroup id="dliSticker">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dlitcStickerValue}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
          <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDlitcSticker" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="perfbyDlitcSticker">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.stickerFreq}"
        rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq  'P'}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Always" />                
            <f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>


    <br/>
    </font>

    </h:form>

    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Here is the error code i am getting with this code:

/indexv2.xhtml at line 88 and column 76  Parent is not composite component or of type ClientBehaviorHolder, type is: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@13fcf10

Caused by:
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException - /indexv2.xhtml at line 88 and column 76  Parent is not composite component or of type ClientBehaviorHolder, type is: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@13fcf10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using 'f:ajax' i used instead richfaces 'a4j:ajax' parameter for the xhtml and while now i have a different issue "The web page with the tags wont show up only text." so i can't really tell if i converted to richfaces correctly but here is what i change let me know if i am right or not thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
          xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"   >

    <h:head>
    <title>QC-Form</title>
    <link href="./css/styles.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </h:head>

    <f:view>

    <h:body>
    <h1 class="title">QC Form</h1>
    <br/> <br/>

      <font face="comic sans MS" size="2" color="#33CCFF">
      <p><b>Enter the information below: </b> </p>
      </font>

    <h:form>

     <font face="comic sans MS" size="2"> 

     <h:panelGroup id="initialInfo">

        <b>Your initials: </b>  
            <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.techNameValue}"/><br/>
        <br/>

        <b>Model #: </b>  
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.modelValue}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="3600" itemLabel="3600" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="7200" itemLabel="7200" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="8300" itemLabel="8300" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="8400" itemLabel="8400" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="8500p" itemLabel="8500p" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="8800" itemLabel="8800" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="9000" itemLabel="9000" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="9008" itemLabel="9008" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="9200" itemLabel="9200" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="9300" itemLabel="9300" />
        </h:selectOneMenu><br/>
         <br/>

        <b>Date : </b>
         <h:outputText  value="#{currentDate}"/>
        <br/> <br/>


        <b>Serial #: </b>  
            <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.serialValue}"/><br/>
        <br/>

        <b>Customer Name: </b>  
            <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.customerNameValue}"/><br/>
        <br/>

        <b>Special Instructions: </b>  
            <h:inputText value="#{qcFormBean.specialInstructionsValue}"/><br/>    

     </h:panelGroup>
    </font>

      <font face="comic sans MS" size="2" color="#33CCFF">
      <p><b>QC Process</b> </p>
      </font>

     <font face="comic sans MS" size="2"> 

    <h:panelGroup id="dliSerial">
     <b>1.Unit Serial number has been applied: </b>
     <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.unitSerialValue}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{qcFormBean.valueQcValue}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <br/>

    </h:panelGroup>

    <br/>
    <b>2.Screen Protector has been applied: </b>
    <h:panelGroup id="dliSticker">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dliStickerValue}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
          <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDliSticker"  limitRender="true" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="perfbyDlitcSticker">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.stickerFreq}"
        rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq  'P'}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Always" />                
            <f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>


    <br/>
    </font>



    </h:form>

    </h:body>
    </f:view>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `f:ajax`s outside of the `h:selectOneMenu`. `h:form` is no `ClientBehaviourHolder` so you can not place a `f:ajax` there. You just can put them into the `h:selectOneMenu`.

---

EDIT: Just remove the `f:ajax` without the parameters, those which wrap the `panelGroup`s and keep the `selectOneMenu`es:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dlitcStickerValue}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDlitcSticker" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

---

EDIT2: Replace the code between `</b>` and the `<br/>` before the `commandButton` with the following code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="dliSticker">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dlitcStickerValue}">
      <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
      <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDlitcSticker" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="perfbyDlitcSticker">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.stickerFreq}"
    rendered="#{!qcFormBean.dliStickerValue eq  'P'}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Always" />                
        <f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Often" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="Seldom" />                
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: That's actually quite confusing since you *can* wrap components with `f:ajax` (see http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/). But I do agree that they are unnecessary in this case.

Comment: So the Ajax event is not neccessary is what your saying?

Comment: I updated my code to represent your suggestion I am not getting the error anymore I am just not getting anything to show in my IE, could you provide an example on how you would type this?

Comment: @GilbertV you need to keep the `f:ajax` tag *inside* the `<h:selectOneMenu>` but the ones outside of it can be removed.

Comment: so just leave out the 'f:ajax' and leave it like this?
<h:panelGroup id="dliSticker">
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{qcFormBean.dlitcStickerValue}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="Pass or Not applicable" />
 <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="FAIL-Mechanical" />
 <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="FAIL-Electrical" />
 <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="FAIL-Cosmetic" />
 <f:selectItem itemValue="S" itemLabel="FAIL-Software" />
          <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDlitcSticker" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
? I will try

Comment: Doing this still causes the parent error to show up. Not sure if this is the answer if there another way or could you provide an example or something?

Comment: This also occurs when i added the f:ajax inside the selectOneMenu <h:selectOneMenu>... <f:ajax> <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyDliSticker" /> </f:ajax> </h:selectOneMenu>

Comment: Do not put `f:ajax` inside another `f:ajax`. Why are you doing this? In your original question there was no `f:ajax` wrapping the one inside the `h:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: Sorry thats because I couldn't understand your answer to be honest still haven't . I removed the first section of 'f:ajax' and left only the one with the event on but it is still giving me the parent issue there.

Comment: There has to be something else i tried your suggestion and i believe that this should work but for some reason i am still getting the parent error. is there a jar i need for this error to go away or something?

Comment: will post my bean but its mostly still getters and setters.Would faces config or web.xml be better?

Comment: First of all post the current .xhtml file with the changes you made since you posted the question.

Comment: just posted the whole xhtml page hopefully this will help, I am thankful for your help btw. Sorry if its frustrating.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47040/discussion-between-gilbert-v-and-user1983983)

Comment: Should I try this with RichFaces to see if it helps?